# How to force scrolling first error in vim's quickfix list up?

Tags: vim

I'm using vim's `:make` to compile my project. After compilation I'm getting the desired results in a quickfix list (by :copen if invoked by `make` and automatically when triggered by vim-dispatch and `:Make`) but the first error (build error or failing test) is always at the bottom of the screen, i.e.

```
<some make output here>
---------<quickfix top line below>
|| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/skramer/c_test/unittest_tests/build'
|| Scanning dependencies of target soundex_test
|| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/skramer/c_test/unittest_tests/build'
|| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/skramer/c_test/unittest_tests/build'
|| [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/soundex_test.dir/soundex.cpp.o
|| [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/soundex_test.dir/soundex_unittest.cpp.o
|| Linking CXX executable soundex_test
|| Running 
|| Running 15 test cases...
soundex_unittest.cpp|17| error in "Encode_SingleLetterWord_RetainsTheSoleLetter": check s.encode("A") == "A001" failed [A000 != A001]
---------<quickfix bottom line>---------
<more errors in make output follow this line>
```

I'd like to get the first make error as the first line in the quickfix list. How can I achieve that? I'd like to avoid grepping the quickfix contents but that may eventually acceptable.

Comment: What about reducing the verbosity of your Makefile?

Comment: This helps a little but the errors are still at the bottom of the list, they are more visible because of the smaller amount of text. I'd however prefer to find the proper solution, something as autotyping `zt` after quickfix list opens